# PHP using PDO to store session in DB doesnt produce the errors i expected

Tags: php, session, pdo, mysqli

**SOLVED : 
answer is in the 2nd post**

i try to store session in DB using PDO, but it doesn't produce errors i expected, please read my code.

here's the code for my session handler class:

```
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    protected $conn = NULL;

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    {
        if(is_null($this->conn))
        {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_advanced';
            $username = 'root';
            $password = 'password';
            try
            {
                 $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
                 $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                 $this->conn = NULL;
                 die('error in open function ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function close()
    {

        echo '<p>close</p>';
        $this->conn = NULL;

        return TRUE;
    }

    public function read($id)
    {

        echo '<p>read</p>';
        $query = 'SELECT data FROM session_table WHERE session_id = :id';
        try
        {
            $pdo = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $pdo->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $pdo->execute();

            //    Kalo query berhasil nemuin id..
            if($pdo->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                list($sessionData) = $pdo->fetch();

                return $sessionData;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->conn = NULL;
            die('error in read function => ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {

        echo '<p>write</p>';
        $query = 'REPLACE INTO session_table(session_id, data) VALUES(:id, :data)';

        try
        {
            $pdo = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $pdo->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $pdo->bindValue(':data', $data);
            $pdo->execute();

            // return the value whether its success or not
            return (bool)$pdo->rowCount();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->conn = NULL;
            die('error in write function => ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {

        echo '<p>destroy</p>';
        $query = 'DELETE FROM session_table WHERE session_id = :id LIMIT 1';

        try
        {
            $pdo = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $pdo->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $pdo->execute();
            $_SESSION = array();
            return (bool)$pdo->rowCount();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->conn = NULL;
            die('error in destroy function => ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function gc($maxLifeTime)
    {

        echo '<p>garbage collection</p>';
        $query = 'DELETE FROM session_table WHERE DATE_ADD(last_accessed INTERVAL :time SECOND) < NOW()';

        try
        {
            $pdo = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $pdo->bindValue(':time', $maxLifeTime);
            $pdo->execute();

            return TRUE;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->conn = NULL;
            die('error in gc function => ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

$SessionHandler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($SessionHandler);
session_name('my_session');

session_start();
```

i remove the session_write_close on purpose. This probably sounds stupid, but i want to get the session error to learn more..

here's session script(using the book's code):

```
require('session_class.php');
?><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DB Session Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Store some dummy data in the session, if no data is present:
if (empty($_SESSION)) {

    $_SESSION['blah'] = 'umlaut';
    $_SESSION['this'] = 3615684.45;
    $_SESSION['that'] = 'blue';

    // Print a message indicating what's going on:
    echo '<p>Session data stored.</p>';

} else { // Print the already-stored data:
    echo '<p>Session Data Exists:<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, 1) . '</pre></p>';
}

// Log the user out, if applicable:
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {

    session_destroy();
    echo '<p>Session destroyed.</p>';
} else { // Otherwise, print the "Log Out" link:
    echo '<a href="session_link.php?logout=true">Log Out</a>';
}

// Reprint the session data:
echo '<p>Session Data:<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, 1) . '</pre></p>';

// Complete the page:
echo '</body>
</html>';

// Write and close the session:
// session_write_close() <<<<<--- I REMOVE THIS ON PURPOSE TO GET ERROR
?>
```

but i dont get any error, then i try to use book's mysqli script to connect db and it produces error i expected because i removed the `session_write_close()`..

can anyone explain why if im using PDO it doesn't generate error? i'm even dont use

```
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

in my session class destructor (on purpose)

**NOTE : I'm doing this on purpose because i want to learn more.**

the error im expecting is like when im using mysqli connection(connection closed  by php at the end of script then session try to write and close but no connection available) :

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/ullman_advance/ch3/ullman_db.php on line 66



Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/ullman_advance/ch3/ullman_db.php on line 66



Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/ullman_advance/ch3/ullman_db.php on line 67



Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/ullman_advance/ch3/ullman_db.php on line 33
```

**update 1**

i recently figured it out that mysqli needs database connection everytime it uses `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli_query` and because of but what im thinking is my pdo also needs db connection when the script ends -> db connection closed -> `MySessionHandler` will try to write and close, but there's no db connection since pdo has been closed by php, but no error produced..

**update 2**

i just tried to pass `session_set_save_handler` function callback and it produces the errors

```
<?php

$conn = NULL;

function open_session()
{
    echo '<p>open session</p>';
    global $conn;
    $_dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_advanced';
    $_username = 'root';
    $_password = 'password';
    $conn = new PDO($_dsn, $_username, $_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return TRUE;
}

function close_session()
{
    echo '<p>close session</p>';
    global $conn;

    $conn = NULL;
    return TRUE;
}

function read_session($sid)
{
    echo '<p>read session</p>';
    global $conn;

    $query = 'SELECT data FROM session_table WHERE session_id = :sid';
    $pdo = $conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindValue(':sid', $sid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->execute();

    if($pdo->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        list($session_data) = $pdo->fetch();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($session_data);
        echo '</pre>';

        return $session_data;
    }
    else
    {
        return '';
    }
}


function write_session($sid, $data)
{
    echo '<p>write session</p>';
    global $conn;

    $query = 'REPLACE INTO session_table(session_id, data) VALUES(:sid, :data)';
    $pdo = $conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindValue(':sid', $sid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->bindValue(':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->execute();

    return $pdo->rowCount();
}

function destroy_session($sid)
{
    echo '<p>destroy session </p>';
    global $conn;

    $query = 'DELETE FROM session_table WHERE session_id = :sid';
    $pdo = $conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindValue(':sid', $sid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo->execute();

    // clean the session array;
    $_SESSION = array();

    return (bool)$pdo->rowCount();
}


function clean_session($expire)
{
    echo '<p>clean session</p>';
    global $conn;

    $query = 'DELETE FROM session_table WHERE DATE_ADD(last_accessed, INTERVAL :expire SECOND) < NOW()';

    $pdo = $conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindValue(':expire', $expire, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdo->execute();

    return $pdo->rowCount();
}

session_set_save_handler('open_session', 'close_session', 'read_session', 'write_session', 'destroy_session', 'clean_session');
session_name('my_session');
session_start();
```

but still when im passing `MySessionHandler` class , it doesn't produce error because of no connection.

Comment: DO NOT USE try..catch with die! It's useless, erroneous and insecure

Comment: erm okay thanks for the tips. btw what is the good/practice to do in the catch block

Comment: use catch block only if you going to handle an error somehow. otherwise just let it go. PHP will inform you and exit the script automatically - so, no need to write 100s of catches.

Comment: oh okay that really help me to become better. thanks! anyway do u have any idea why my pdo script above doesn't produce errors?

Comment: Some questions cannot be answered at glance, but after some debugging only. Why don't you want to debug your code a little, if you think that behavior is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

sorry guys my mistake actually its a pretty easy answer why `MySessionHandler` class doesnt produce error wihtout `session_write_close()` in the end of script,

`session_set_save_handler()` by default will register `session_write_close()` to `register_shutdown_function()`

so if u want to make your own shutdown function for session then use :
`session_set_save_handler($SessionClass, FALSE)` , if u do this then u must provide `session_write_close()` in your class destructor

source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

thanks for the tips and your attention

Comment: Accept your answer then it's clear it's answered. Not that somebody works though the wall of text then realizing in the end it was for nothing.